# How get the select type name and the selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing a funny issue for you !

Using JQuery I want to get the name attribute of the select type and the value of the selected option.
in this example I want this result

```
var selectTypeName = "cars"
var selectedOption = "volvo"
```

thanks !

```js
$( "select" )
  .change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
    $( "div" ).text( str );
  })
  .trigger( "change" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/action_page.php">
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add a working code snippet demonstrating your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9oj3ufL0/12/

```
$( "select" )
  .change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
        var selectTypeName = $(this).closest("select").attr("name");
      var selectedOption = $( this ).text();
      str += "selectTypeName: " + selectTypeName + ",  selectedOption:" + selectedOption + " ";
    });
    $( "div" ).text( str );
  })
  .trigger( "change" );
```

And I've added a  on html section.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var selectTypeName = $("SELECTOR").attr('name');
var selectTypeName = $("SELECTOR").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `attr` to get any attribute you need:

```
var selectTypeName = $("select").attr("name");
```

also you can limit the selection to a specific name using **name selector**:

```
var selectedOption= $('select[name=cars]').val();
```

if you want to use the extracted name in first query use this:

```
var selectedOption= $('select[name=' + selectTypeName +' ]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code is correct.
You didn't have the div that you're trying to populate in your HTML.

See:
https://jsfiddle.net/9oj3ufL0/6/

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <div>
    </div>
    <select name="cars">
```

Answer (score 0):

i updated your fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/9oj3ufL0/22/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "select" ).change(function() {
var str = "";
var name="";
$( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
  str += $( this ).text() + " ";
  name=$(this).parent().attr("name");
});
 alert(name);
 });
});
```